# Can I preselect items in TYPO3's select elements in TCA?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I am configuring a custom backend field in pages TCA. There, I added a new select type field, with the renderType `selectCheckBox`. The items to be selected are filled via an `itemsProcFunc` that uses a custom PHP function.

Is there a way to preselect certain, or all of the items when returning them in the `itemsProcFunc` via `$PA[items]`?

Comment: You can use the "default" property but this is static. I assume you want to set the default values dynamically too?

Comment: That would be prefered, yes. For now, I have come to terms with the fact that it's not possible right now.

Comment: You may also want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56646328/typo3-tca-make-the-default-value-dynamic Unfortunately there is no answer there either, but the comments might help.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways exist depending on use case:

- For content records added added through the new content wizard, see pageTSconfig `defValues` (bottom of page https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/Mod.html). This is not the implementation you should use, as you mention you want this to be done for the `pages` table, but I mention it for completeness in case other users come to this question through searches.
- For any record type including content records, see FormEngine processors (which unfortunately are *significantly* harder to use) - https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/FormEngine/Rendering/Index.html